# What do Azteca's words mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, antz

In **[Antz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antz)**, Azteca & Weaver have this conversation

> Azteca: What happened to Z ?
>
> Weaver: He's takin' a personal day, so I'm fillin' in.
>
> Azteca: You fill in any more, and you'll **explode**.

What does she mean with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### She says it because of Weaver's size, implying he is huge.

Weaver is a soldier ant, much larger and stronger than worker ants. Azteca, being use to other worker ants, is largely impressed by Weaver's size. When she uses the expression **filling in** (metaphor for replacing someone), she jokes with the literal meaning (completing or growing something) and says he will explode if he gets any bigger. In other words, he is already so big, that his body won't handle it if he grows anymore.